# Ubuntu operated from raspberry PI, is it possible?

Tags: raspberrypi

Is it possible to have Ubuntu put onto a 32gb sd card and be operated from a raspberry PI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this isn't possible. The Raspberry is ARMv6-based, Ubuntu only supports ARMv7 and above. I've recently seen Ubuntu on a LemonBoard (Cortex A9), but for the Raspberry PI, Debian Wheezy is the obvious choice (at least for me - others might prefer Arch).